# Youtube API - How to set game title

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm writing a project in C# with the purpose to automate my streaming preparations.

I have succeeded with creating a stream and a broadcast, but I fail when it comes to assigning a video game title to the broadcast.

I receive status 200 but still it won't change.

```cs
liveBroadcast = new LiveBroadcast();
liveBroadcast.Status = new LiveBroadcastStatus();
liveBroadcast.Status.PrivacyStatus = "private";
liveBroadcast.Snippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet();
liveBroadcast.Snippet.Title = title;
liveBroadcast.Snippet.Description = description;
liveBroadcast.Snippet.ScheduledStartTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 19, 0, 0, 0);
liveBroadcast.Snippet.ScheduledEndTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 21, 0, 0, 0);
liveBroadcast.TopicDetails = new LiveBroadcastTopicDetails();
liveBroadcast.TopicDetails.Topics = new List<LiveBroadcastTopic>();

var liveBroadcastTopic = new LiveBroadcastTopic();
liveBroadcastTopic.Type = "videoGame";
liveBroadcastTopic.Unmatched = false;
liveBroadcastTopic.Snippet = new LiveBroadcastTopicSnippet();
liveBroadcastTopic.Snippet.Name = "ARMA 3";
liveBroadcastTopic.Snippet.ReleaseDate = "2013";

liveBroadcast.TopicDetails.Topics.Add(liveBroadcastTopic);

liveBroadcast = await youtubeService.LiveBroadcasts.Insert(liveBroadcast, "status,snippet,topicDetails").ExecuteAsync();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected title and how are you setting it the title in C#?

Comment: Where did you get the string "videoGame" from (I couldn't find the documentation for this)? Are you sure this is correct? When manually setting the category of your stream, the option "Gaming" has value `20` in the html dropdown. Try `liveBroadcastTopic.Type = "20";` or `liveBroadcastTopic.Type = "gaming";`.

Comment: I also advise you to ask a separate question concerning the monetization, as two unrelated question in one post make it hard to give good answers.

Comment: @paolo: The category "gaming" is already selected and works and I get an error from the LiveBroadcastTopic from Googles API whenever I select a wrong answer. But it's the game title which is wrong. I will remove monetization from this question.

Comment: @noogui: Expected game title "Arma 3" as you see in the posted code, I attempt to set it with "LiveBroadcastTopic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube has not yet implemented a way to set the game title of a stream through their API.

So my solution for this was to create a browser class which imported the cookies from the installed browser and just performed regular posts to the form on youtubes video editing page.

Not the cleanest or the best approach, but it works.

This approach will be deprecated and edited when they implement it in their API. (At the moment unknown when)